# What is wrong with this argument: Range Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Suppose we are in 2D and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $e_v$ for some transformation surjective $T$

Define: $U=\operatorname{range}(T-\lambda I) $

I want understand what the range space here. $U$ must have dimension less than 2, particularly dimension 1, as the null space is the eigenvector space which is given above.

Suppose the eigenvector space related to this $\lambda$ is $\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$.

So everything except $\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$ must be in $U$.

Therefore $\operatorname{span}\{(1,2)\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{(1,3)\}$ must be in $U$.

But notice that $\operatorname{span}\{(1,2)\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{(1,3)\}$ are linearly independent.

Thus $U$ has two linearly independant vectors.

Thus $U$ has at least dimension 2. This contradicts the statement that $U$ has dimension less than 2.

What is wrong with this argument? Or is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking your argument, we can show that both $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,3)$ cannot be in $U$. Say they were in $U$, then $U$ being a subspace must be closed under vector operations. This means $a-b=(0,-1) \in U$. But then $(1,2)+(0,-1)=(1,1) \in U$ as well. This is a contradiction by your own reasoning that $(1,1) \not\in U$.

---

**Further addition to answer your query in the comment:**

Let $S=T-\lambda I$, we want to know the range of $S$ provided we know that the null space of $S$ is spanned by $u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. Let the matrix representation of $S$ be $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$. Then with $Su=0$, we get
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\c&-c\end{bmatrix}.$$

Recall range of $S$ is just the span of the columns of $S$. So without any more information the best we can say is that

1. If $a=c=0$, then the range is just $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.
2. If either of them is non-zero, say $a \neq 0$, then the 
   range is $1$ dimensional and is spanned by the vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks. So then what is in U exactly? How can we determine its contents only knowing span{(1,1)} is the null space? I thought the range space automatically consists of all vectors not in the null space.

Comment: @RahulDeora are you familiar with rank-nullity theorem? based on that one can say $\text{dim (range)} T +\text{dim (nullspace)} T=\text{dim (domain space)}$. With this, one can easily see if we are in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and null space is of dimension one then the range space can only be $1-$dimensional. Hence it cannot contain everything that is NOT in the null space.

Comment: @RahulDeora I have added a bit more to my answer to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why "everything except $\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$ is in $U$".  In fact it is false.

Simple example:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Then for $\lambda=1$,
$$
T-I=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so $U=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1)\}$ does not contain $(1,2)$ or $(1,3)$, for example.

Another example, $T$ is not self-adjoint:
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you can check eigenvector $(1,1)$ with eigenvalue $\lambda=2$.  We have
$$
T-2I=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $U=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}$, again does not contain $(1,2)$ or $(1,3)$.

Comment: In your second example, if (1,1) is in the null space of T-2I, then shouldnt everything else be in its range space? or is that not how range spaces work?

Comment: No, that is not how range spaces work.  Range space looks at where everything get sent to, not sent from.